# StackedBarChart draw marker for different yValues

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

im trying to draw a marker on a stacked bar chart. My first approach was to create a subclass of ChartMarker by following the [iOS-Charts BalloonMarker](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/ChartsDemo/Classes/Components/BalloonMarker.swift) example on github, and it worked! The problem now is showing the correct value when i click on the chart bar, because the ChartDataEntry contains the sum of all the values in that axis. I also tried to use the method:

```
func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: ChartHighlight) {
```

To see if i could get the dataSetIndex to tell me at which level of the bar chart im clicking on, but no luck, the dataSetIndex always returns 0.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where's your 'following example link'?

Comment: Sorry I edited the question. The example is on the ios-charts library, in the Demo section.

Comment: You still need to show your code, for the others to see the difference of your implementation.

Comment: The code is indifferent :) the only problem here is to get the correct yIndex on the stackedBarChart

Comment: There must be some different implementation of your code (maybe not in this class), or no one can help you here. If you know some where in the code might be related, it's better to show more in the question.

Comment: You may want to have a try on `highlight.stackIndex`

Comment: Yeah you are absolutely right @zcui93 , highlight.stackIndex is the answer!! Thank you very much.

P.S.: if you to add a response I can accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `ChartHighlight` class, there's a property called `stackIndex` where the associated private property `_stackIndex` has the explanation of

> index which value of a stacked bar entry is highlighted

so you should be able to access the highlighted index by `highlight.stackIndex`

Cheers